# is there anyway to make this cool chat bubble widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'd try thinking how to make this chat bubble `widget` but can't find any way, i'd tried to check on this package [flutter_chat_bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble)  but nothing similar to the design i want to achieve, if you know something please tell me.

i really don't have anything in mind right now to make this widget

[image]

Comment: Hey this looks interesting, I am excited to try this on my own, I'll share the code once I'm done with it... It'll take some time as I'm busy with something rn, but I'll get back to you in a few hours... I'll suggest you try it as well, looks achievable with some containers, sizedbox and padding.

Comment: Alriiigghhtttt, yeaah if you don't mind

Comment: Try creating one with Column and Container.

Comment: You should show what you have done so others can edit it for you. There are no similar package to what you want. You have to make it on your own. Just like rahul mentioned: use Containers inside Columns

Comment: yeah what i mean is i what to make on my own but i don't know how to make the triangle shape pointing to the avatar, but it's okay mohammad darvishi already make it :) thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              painter: Bubble(),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:8,horizontal:15 ),
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .7,
                ),
                child:   const Padding(
                  padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'your text',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin:  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15,vertical: 5),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle
                ),
                child: const Icon(Icons.image,size: 30,color: Colors.white,))
          ],
        ),
```

And Bubble widgetis:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:koja/theme/theme.dart';

class Bubble extends CustomPainter {
  double _radius = 5.0;
  double _x = 10.0;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          0,
          0,
          size.width - _x,
          size.height-10,
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_radius),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
          topRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(_radius),
        ),
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.grey
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(20,size.height-12);
    path.lineTo(30,size.height);
    path.lineTo(40,size.height-10);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          0,
          0.0,
          size.width,
          size.height,
        ),
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.grey
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code with custom `clipper`

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 200,
                child: Center(child: Text("Hello")),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: TringleShape(),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

here is custom `pathClipper`

```
class TringleShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  TringleShape();

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double width = size.width;
    double height = size.height;
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(width, 0);
    path.lineTo(width/2, height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```